# Change an element's CSS class with PHP

Tags: php, css

How can I change a CSS class of an HTML element in response to a changing page using PHP?

I already got the solution exactly like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript) but this solution is for Javascript.

Basically, I want to add additional class when a certain IF condition is met.
This is my code.

```
<li <?php if ($selected == "profile") echo 'class="active"'; ?> class="dropdown">
<a href="">Profile</a>
</li>
```

From my code, you can see that the `<li>` already got a class in it. So, when I `echo` another class in `IF` condition, it completely change to the class in `IF` condition.

What I need is an extra class, not different class. How can I do that?

Comment: class="dropdown <?php if ($selected == "profile") echo 'active'; ?>"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just move it?

```
<li class="dropdown<?php if ($selected == "profile") echo ' active'; ?>">
```

This results in `class="dropdown active"`, which is perfectly fine in HTML - you can have multiple space-separated classes on an element. All CSS rules targeting either of the two will be applied, and you can even combine them to require both:

```
li.active.dropdown {
  /* Underline active dropdown elements */
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: Oh, that's it! I just need to declare the condition in the class. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
 <li class="dropdown <?php if ($selected == "profile") echo 'active'; ?>">
    <a href="">Profile</a>
 </li>
```

try this

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
<li class="<?php if ($selected == "profile") echo 'active'; ?> OTHER CONDITION HERE ">
    <a href="">Profile</a>
</li>
```